# Setting TCP_KEEPALIVE_THRESHOLD in Netty on Solaris

Tags: tcp, netty

As mentioned in documentation below, Solaris supports setting of TCP_KEEPALIVE_THRESHOLD and TCP_KEEPALIVE_ABORT_THRESHOLD per socket:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/819-2724/fsvdh/index.html

We are using Netty to set SO_KEEPALIVE to true and changing interval in OS:

> ndd -set /dev/tcp tcp_keepalive_interval 1440000

Is there any way in Netty to set keepalive wait/abort interval per socket? If not, is there any interface or native method that we can use for this?

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/bootstrap/AbstractBootstrap.html#option(io.netty.channel.ChannelOption,%20T)):

Method Option():

> Allow to specify a ChannelOption which is used for the Channel
>   instances once they got created. Use a value of null to remove a
>   previous set ChannelOption

Another solution I think should work is get the `ServerBootstrap` object and set the option false using:

```
...
ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
                b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                 .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                 .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, false)
                 .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
...
```

It should works in Netty 4 and 5. Hope it helps :)